# Visual C# mouse events on a panel not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouse

I'm using Visual C# 2008 and am stuck with mouse events on a panel. I have defined a mouse down, mouse leave, mouse enter. I made it very simple.

I pressed on the panel selected those events I needed and it auto generated my needed code for firing a mouse events.

Inserted a breakpoint in my recieving eventcode, but it will never be firing.

Is there a bug in Visual C#? I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Some code, `Form1.Designer`:

```
this.pagepanel.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pagepanel_MouseDown);
this.pagepanel.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.pagepanel_MouseEnter);
this.pagepanel.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.pagepanel_MouseLeave);
```

Form1.cs:

```
private void pagepanel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
private void pagepanel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

private void pagepanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mode == MODE_BUTTON)
    {
        int x = e.X;
        int y = e.Y;

        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Right: break;
            case MouseButtons.Left:   break;
            case MouseButtons.Middle: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code and we might be able to help you :D

Comment: Post some code. A bug in c# with VS2008, I think we would have noticed that by now...

Comment: You are setting the Cursor property of the form, not of the panel, so good odds you don't see it change the cursor.  Nor does it make sense to change the cursor. Very hard to guess what "mode" might do.

Comment: I think if you have some control on the panel then if the event's fire for the controls then the panel's events doesn't fire. I'm no sure but it's better to check it

Comment: I have some control for the Form. Like Form_Load and Container_Splittermoved, Container_Panel_SizeChanged

Comment: I made a new empty project... Form with one panel and also events to fired... And it was working just fine. So something in my old project causing my events to be not fired... hmmmm

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your panel is in the front. Use *bring to front* in the designer. Maybe another container control is getting in the way.

Comment: I found it :-), I needed to set my panel to enabled.

Thanks for all answers
Best Regards
Mikael

Comment: what? :D that was a hard one to catch